# use selectors in variable jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

i have to made functionality like [this](http://www.biz.konicaminolta.com/lineup/index.html) on click of a link it will show the product details in a popup like box 
this is using a big jquery code i didn't understand

and here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hg4zp/2/)
 i am trying to give some links same class with different #tags to show the div 
and i want that when i click on link it resolves the href value of the same and show the corresponding result but it didnt works 
can somebody suggest the right way 
here is my JS

```
$(".show").click(function() {
    var link = $('this').attr('href');
  $(link).show();

});
```

and html

```
<a href="#popup" id="show" class="show">a</a>
<a href="#popup1" id="show1" class="show">b</a>
<a href="#popup2" id="show2" class="show">c</a>
```

i want to show #popup on anchor click

full code on [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hg4zp/2/) and i want [this functionality](http://www.biz.konicaminolta.com/lineup/index.html)

Comment: You are trying to show a object that has the href of your link, that wouldn't work. What exactly do you like to be showed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should call `$(this)`, not `$('this')`

- `$(this)` wraps the object referred to by `this` inside a jQuery object,
- `$('this')` will traverse all of your document looking for html nodes tagged `this` (much like `$('div')` will look for html nodes tagged `div`); since there isn't any, it will select an empty list of nodes.

Working fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Hg4zp/3/

( there also was a typo, calling `.hide(")` instead of `.hide()` )

Comment: thanks its worked 
and .hide() was a mistake i am trying something thanks for this too

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
$(".show").click(function (e) { //<-----pass the event here
   e.preventDefault(); //<--------------stop the default behavior of the link
   var link = $(this).attr('href'); //<-remove the quotes $(this)
   $(link).show();
});

$(".close").click(function () {
   $(this).closest("div.popupbox").hide(); //<----use .hide(); not .hide(");
});
```

You should use `preventDefault()` in these cases to stop the jump which take place when a link get clicked.