# Don't want page jump

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, page-jump

Previous problam solved @ [use selectors in variable jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15380047/use-selectors-in-variable-jquery) on same coe

i have to made functionality like [this](http://www.biz.konicaminolta.com/lineup/index.html) 
this is using a big jquery code i didn't understand

and here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hg4zp/4/)
 i have make the same functionality but when it is clicked the page jumps to that element 
i dont want page to jump i need some fadein and out

```
$(".show").click(function() {
    var link = $('this').attr('href');
  $(link).show();

});

$(".close").click(function() {
  $(this).closest("div.popupbox").hide();
});
```

and html

```
<a href="#popup" id="show" class="show">a</a>
<a href="#popup1" id="show1" class="show">b</a>
<a href="#popup2" id="show2" class="show">c</a>
```

i want to show #popup on anchor click but dont want to page jump/scroll to that id 
i have given `top:10000px` in fiddle for testing this issue because in my original page it moves to particular element

full code on [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hg4zp/4/) and i want [this functionality](http://www.biz.konicaminolta.com/lineup/index.html)

Comment: well ... and your question is? This looks like a request to me ... and you didn't even ask please ...

Comment: how to stop page jump im my website

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with this one:

```
$(".show").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var link = $(this).attr('href'); //<----remove quotes in $('this')
  $(link).fadeIn(); // <-------------use fadeIn() instead
});

$(".close").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).closest("div.popupbox").hide();
});
```

and adjust the `top:100000px` to something lesser one like `50px`

Answer (score 1):

Use `preventDefault()`

```
$(".show").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
    $(link).show().animate(
    {
        scrollTop: $(link).offset().top
    },800);;

});

$(".close").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).closest("div.popupbox").hide();
  $('body,html').animate(
    {
        scrollTop: 0
    }, 800);
});
```

Comment: its working but its stopped jumping scroll down you will see image

Comment: @SahilPopli i have updated my answer see if thats works for you

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#foo',function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `event.preventDefault()`

```
$(".show").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
    $(link).show();

});

$(".close").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest("div.popupbox").hide();
});
```

Docs http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Comment: can you edit it in fiddle its not working for me a same answer i also tested before